# Ошибка: имя типа или пространства имен отсутствует в пространстве имен

Tags: c#

```
using System.drawing;
```

В C# выдает:

> `Ошибка    1   Имя типа или пространства имен "drawing" отсутствует в пространстве имен "System" (пропущена ссылка на сборку?) E:\C#\librery\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs    5   14  ConsoleApplication1`

Я так понимаю, мне надо что-то загрузить, вот только что и где?

Answer (score 1):

В C# регистр букв имеет значение. Drawing и drawing - это два разных идентификатора. Ошибка говорит о том, что в пространстве имен System нет имени drawing. И там его действительно нет. Надо так:

```
using System.Drawing;
```

Comment: ПРи изминении ошыбка не изщезла
я скачал Drawing.dll вот только не знаю куда его вставить,
подскажи плис

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо добавить ссылку на сборку System.Drawing.dll (консольной приложение, по умолчанию не добавляется). Ну и на всякий случай: drawing с большой буквы: 
    using System.Drawing;